# is it necessary to put this in useMemo ? (date calculations)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use a timer and I want to ask you should I wrap this with useMemo and callback ?

without:

```
const [time, setTime] = useState();

const calculateInitialDuration = (endDate: string, today: Date): CountdownResult => {
  const futureDate = new Date(endDate)
  const days = differenceInDays(futureDate, today)
  const hours = differenceInHours(futureDate, today) % 24
  const minutes = differenceInMinutes(futureDate, today) % 60
  const seconds = differenceInSeconds(futureDate, today) % 60
  return { days, hours, minutes, seconds }
}

  useEffect(() => {

    const timer = setInterval(() => 
      setTime(calculateInitialDuration(expire_date, new Date())), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  })
```

With memos

```
  const calculateInitialDuration = useCallback(() => {
    const days = calcDay;
    const hours = calcHours;
    const minutes = calcMinute;
    const seconds = calcSeconds;
    return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
  }, [time]);


  const calcDay = useMemo(() => (differenceInDays(new Date(expire_date), new Date())), [time]);
  const calcHours = useMemo(() => (differenceInHours(new Date(expire_date), new Date()) % 24), [time]);
  const calcMinute = useMemo(() => (differenceInMinutes(new Date(expire_date), new Date()) % 60), [time]);
  const calcSeconds = useMemo(() => (differenceInSeconds(new Date(expire_date), new Date()) % 60), [time]);
```

so is that necessary to wrap all calculations with memo or should I use the simple without useMemo ?

the second problem it does not lose 1 second, sometimes it looses 2 seconds

Comment: Your second code has no effect with `setInterval`?

Comment: Your first code has an effect without dependencies, which will run on every render - that can't be desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to try to achieve an exact time different in the browser. setInterval/setTimeout can only guarantee you a minimal time when your function will be called.
As for memoization: the usual recommendation to use it - use it for heavy calculation OR if you pass some variable to another component as a prop.
For example:

```
const memoized = useMemo(() => {....}, [])
return <SomeComponent prop={memoized}/>
```

Unless you are in one of the above situations and have visible problems with performance, using unnecessary memoization may end up being worse for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to calculate a date difference, wouldn't you want it to be from the specific instance that the method was called?

I.E. Instead of using `new Date()` for every call, wouldn't it make more sense to have `Date now = new Date();` and then pass in `now` for each call?

At the very least, that would remove the loss in seconds, would it not?

EDIT: Realizing this question is in relation to react, which I am unfortunately unfamiliar with. If this answer is somehow correct, then awesome. Otherwise, sorry for wasting your time.